# Mis imagenes no se ven en Vercel

Tags: javascript, html, express, nodemailer, vercel

Mi problema radica en que cuando subi todo el backend a vercel utilizando nodemailer y express (funciona perfecto) pero las imagenes no se muestran.Intente muchas formas de resolverlo, no se si debo hacer alguna peticion al servidor o simplemente estoy poniendo mal la ruta de las imagenes

[image: imagenes]

```html
<img src="public/a746207.jpg"class="absolute block -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 top-1/2 left-1/2" alt="..." />
```

Esa es la ruta que estoy dando para que se muestren las imagenes pero no funcionan, me da error 404

Soy medianamente nuevo en este mundo. No entiendo muy bien como resolver este problema

Comment: Para que se puedan mostrar bien en la web deberás cambiar la ruta de la imagen por `/public/....` añadiendo la barra al inicio.
Es posible incluso que no sea necesario poner `/public`.